# How To Remove (%0D) in python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```py
import requests
nexmokey = 'mykey'
nexmosec = 'mysecretkey'

nexmoBal = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/account/get-balance?api_key={}&api_secret={}'.format(nexmokey,nexmosec)
rr = requests.get(nexmoBal)
print(rr.url)
```

I would like to send a request to post at

`https://rest.nexmo.com/account/get-balance?api_key=mykey&api_secret=mysecretkey`

but why does `%0D` appear?

`https://rest.nexmo.com/account/get-balance?api_key=mykey%0D&api_secret=mysecretkey%0D`

Comment: Are you sure your strings do not contain newline characters?

Comment: %0D character is a carriage return

Comment: The code you have posted does not reproduce the problem you are describing, which sounds like it would be caused by carriage returns in your `nexmo` strings. You can remove them by stripping the strings.

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get` expects parameters like `api_secret=my_secret` to be provided through the `params` argument, not as part of the URL, which is URL-encoded for you.

Use this:

```
nexmoBal = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/account/get-balance'
rr = requests.get(nexmoBal, params={'api_key': nexmokey, 'api_secret': nexmosec})
```

The fact that `%0D` ends up in there, indicates you have a character #13 (0D hexadecimal) in there, which is a carriage return (part of the end of line on Windows systems) - probably because you are reading the key and secret from some file and didn't include them in the example code.

Also, note that you mention you want to post, but you're calling `.get()`.

Comment: Technically 0D is carriage return,  0A is linefeed.

Comment: You're right of course, corrected - doubt that was the -1 though :)